# Javascript: What does this code snippet do and error code Uncaught TypeError: allEnemies.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on completing a simple canvas game.  I'm getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: allEnemies.forEach is not a function

Why am I getting this error?

I show below how I declared allEnemies.  According to the instructions allEnemies is supposed to be an array of objects.

Is my declaration of allEnemies wrong or is the object Enemy declared wrong?

This is the declaration of Enemy which I think they are trying to declare an object(I have never seen an object declaration like this)  I think this is an IIFE correct?

```
var Enemy = function() {
    // Variables applied to each of our instances go here,
    // we've provided one for you to get started

    // The image/sprite for our enemies, this uses
    // a helper we've provided to easily load images
    this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.
```

Here is the entire app.js file:

```
    // Enemies our player must avoid
var Enemy = function() {
    // Variables applied to each of our instances go here,
    // we've provided one for you to get started

    // The image/sprite for our enemies, this uses
    // a helper we've provided to easily load images
    this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
}

// Update the enemy's position, required method for game
// Parameter: dt, a time delta between ticks
Enemy.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    // You should multiply any movement by the dt parameter
    // which will ensure the game runs at the same speed for
    // all computers.
}

// Draw the enemy on the screen, required method for game
Enemy.prototype.render = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
}

// Now write your own player class
// This class requires an update(), render() and
// a handleInput() method.
var Player = function() {
    // Variables applied to each of our instances go here,
    // we've provided one for you to get started


    this.sprite = 'images/char-pink-girl.png';
}

// Now instantiate your objects.
// Place all enemy objects in an array called allEnemies
// Place the player object in a variable called player
var allEnemies = [];
allEnemies = Enemy;

var player = Player;


// This listens for key presses and sends the keys to your
// Player.handleInput() method. You don't need to modify this.
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var allowedKeys = {
        37: 'left',
        38: 'up',
        39: 'right',
        40: 'down'
    };

    player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
});
```

This is the line of code that is giving me the type of error:

```
allEnemies.forEach(function(enemy) {
```

here is the rest of the function declaration:

```
function updateEntities(dt) {
        allEnemies.forEach(function(enemy) {
            enemy.update(dt);
        });
        player.update();
    }
```

Comment: You surely want: `allEnemies.push(Enemy);` instead of `allEnemies = Enemy;` But i suspect there are many other things wrong in your code

Comment: what I'm trying to do is place the enemy object into the array allEnemies.  Does this change your answer?

Comment: okay I did this: allEnemies.push(new Enemy);    --> the errors about enemy went away.  Now I do have other errors which I already know the code is imcomplete.  So I would say this is answered.  I will work on other issues and make sure this still works.  For some reason I don't see the answered check mark under this answer??

Answer (score 2):

In line 1 `allEnemies` is an array.
The next line it becomes `Enemy`.

```
var allEnemies = [];
allEnemies = Enemy;
```

`Enemy` is a function.
`allEnemies` is now a function.

Function.prototype.forEach is `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here

```
   allEnemies = Enemy;
```

You declared **allEnemies** as an array but you overrode it with the above statement. Now **allEnemies** is a simple function not an array. Hence forEach is undefined.

To create an array of Enemy objects, you should do :

```
   allEnemies.push(Enemy);
```

Comment: The goal is to create an array of objects.  Does this understanding change your answer?

Comment: I believe you need to do allEnemies.push(Enemy).

Comment: I implemented allEnemies.push(Enemy) and now I'm getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: allEnemies is not defined.  Can anyone help me with this.  I don't know what this means because I defined it as var allEnemies = []; I thought the problem is the order of loading the .js files but I error occurs in the engine.js file so I loaded app.js first and that didn't help.  the error occurs here where I'm looping over the array using foreach: allEnemies.forEach(function(enemy) {